# AutoML model evaluation shows good results, but evaluation over separate test set is not as good

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm currently using AutoML to train a model, which I'm later evaluating against a separate test set not provided to Vertex AI. When training the model, the model performance metrics (e.g. accuracy, AUC ROC, AUC PR, etc) generated by Vertex look pretty good. However, compared against an evaluation run over my separate test set, it's performing significantly worse.

What could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The usual cause for this is that the data distribution is different between the test set used by Vertex AI for generating the evaluation metrics and the separate test set. You can use Vertex AI's [model monitoring service](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/model-monitoring/model-monitoring-batch-predictions) to help detect skewness between the training data and the data you're testing with.

One reason why the data could be skewed is that your data is ordered chronologically. i.e. you're testing against data that's newer than the training data. In this case, you should use a [chronological data split](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/classification-regression/prepare-data#time). This sets an appropriate validation (and test set) that can be used by the AutoML algorithm find architectures that generalize better to the distribution of data that you'll serve with.